# Are these endian transformations correct?

Tags: endianness

I am struggling to figure this out, I am trying to represent a 32bit variable in both big and little endian. For the sake of argument let's say we try the number, "666."

Big Endian: 0010 1001 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000

Little Endian: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 1001 1010

Is this correct, or is my thinking wrong here?

Comment: You're showing 28 bit numbers.

Comment: larsman's right..and even if they were 32 your conversion is wrong. Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Big endian means that the most significant digit is on the far left. The most significant digit in a 32-bit number is over two billion, then the next one is one billion, etc. Needless to say, this means that a big endian representation of 666 is going to have a *lot* of zeroes on the left before you reach any ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

666 (decimal) as 32-bit binary is represented as:

`[0000 0000] [0000 0000] [0000 0010] [1001 1010]`  (big endian, most significant byte first))

`[1001 1010] [0000 0010] [0000 0000] [0000 0000]`  (little endian, least significant byte first)

[Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

(I have used square brackets to group 4-bit nibbles into bytes)

Comment: are you sure? isn't a byte made of 8 bit? seems 4 from your conversion